# ActiveRecord format phone numbers

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have an old MySQL database field with phone numbers in the following format:

```
(xxx) xxx-xxxx
```

I would like to change them to just numbers(`xxxxxxxxxx`). I found the solution on the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423420/format-phone-numbers-in-mysql) but I want to write a rake file to do this.

```
UPDATE table_name set PhoneCol = REPLACE(PhoneCol, '(', '');
UPDATE table_name set PhoneCol = REPLACE(PhoneCol, ') ', '-');
```

How do I run these commands on **Active Record**? I've worked it out to

```
 Model.update_all(phone: ???)
```

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483049/how-to-execute-a-raw-update-sql-with-dynamic-binding-in-rails

Comment: Why you need Rakefile? You could do it using Rails console.. Right ?

Comment: @User089247 If that's the need, why not fix the actual source from where it is coming.. Why double work?

Comment: @BroiSatse : For this case a reversible migration would work, but in many cases, for example I had to update once all mobile numbers which were like (xxx) -xxxx and xxx- xxxx to xxx xxxx, in that case it won't be reversible, so a rake task was the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run raw SQL query:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table_name set PhoneCol = REPLACE(PhoneCol, '(', '');")
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("UPDATE table_name set PhoneCol = REPLACE(PhoneCol, ') ', '-');")
```

or as you yourself said, use `update_all`:

```
Model.update_all("'PhoneCol' =  REPLACE(PhoneCol, '(', '')")
Model.update_all("'PhoneCol' =  REPLACE(PhoneCol, ') ', '-')")
```

If you're looking forward to undo the changes then you can create two rake tasks:

```
namespace :phone_column do
  desc "Update phone column from (xxx) -xxxx to xxx-xxxx"
  task :update => :environment do
    Model.update_all("'PhoneCol' =  REPLACE(PhoneCol, '(', '')")
    Model.update_all("'PhoneCol' =  REPLACE(PhoneCol, ') ', '-')")
  end

  # NOTE: running this task can mess up the data if you have not run the previous task before
  desc "Reverse xxx-xxxx to (xxx) -xxxx"
  task :reverse => :environment do
    Model.update_all("'PhoneCol' =  CONCAT('(', SUBSTRING_INDEX(PhoneCol, '-', 1), ') ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(PhoneCol, '-', 2), '-', SUBSTRING_INDEX(PhoneCol, '-', -1))")
  end
end
```

I would have recommended putting this in a migration file with `up` and `down` methods, but that's not a good way of updating data like this, i.e. migration files should always deal with schema changes, not the data update in your database. Because, when you create new migration as your project grows, you won't have any other choice to run rollback on that migration without referring to its version number, and by any chance if you(or someone else) miss that, you may face a serious data loss on production server. That's why your update scripts should be in a rake tasks(which does NOT cover guarantee of your data update being REVERSIBLE).

Comment: Works well. But how do I undo changes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should store phone numbers in the proper format, which is the [ITU E.164 Format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164). There's a Ruby port of [Google’s libphonenumber](https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/) called [global_phone](https://github.com/sstephenson/global_phone), which parses all kinds of crazy input people come up with. You can sanitize all numbers in a specific database column with the following snippet:

```
Model.find_each do |model|
  normalized_number = GlobalPhone.normalize(model.phone_number)
  model.update_attribute('phone_number', normalized_number)
end
```

I also recommend using `before_validation` callbacks, or, if you need it for many columns, a Gem such as [attribute_normalizer](https://github.com/mdeering/attribute_normalizer) which will help you sanitize new records as the users enter new numbers. You could then define your own normalizer which normalizes phone numbers using the global_phone Gem.

Lastly, presenting the numbers in a format suitable for the user is the responsibility of the view layer, where you could take the globally unambiguous E.164 formatted numbers and reformat them as you like, just like you would do with a `Date` column, for example. If you like to get real fancy, you could also override the getters for the involved attributes, so that calling `model.phone_number` directly returns a parsed `GlobalPhone::Number` object instead of a string; this way you can keep the view clean of calls to `GlobalPhone.parse`.